# Why one of the examples of recursion works and one doesn't? Please explain the logic on how its working

Tags: javascript, recursion

```
function countup(n) {
        if (n > 0) {
         const countArray = countup(n - 1);
          countArray.push(n);
          return countArray;
        }
  }
 console.log(countup(10));
```

//Function below works, Above doesn't. Why?

```
function countup(n) {
 if (n < 1) {
    return [];
 } else {
    const countArray = countup(n - 1);
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}
console.log(countup(10));
```

//The only difference seems to be the empty array [] created when n < 1.How countArray becomes an array? //Am I missing something?

Comment: Cause if `n` is lower equal 0, you implicitly return undefined and you cannot push to undefined. In the second case you correctly return an array.

Comment: Can you explain what evidence you have that "one ... works and one doesn't"?

Comment: I ran those in chrome console & jsbin.com

Comment: @ScottHunter, because, if they both worked then he wouldn't have posted the question?

Comment: @Dabrowski: The point of a request for clarification like Scott Hunter asked is to get the  OP to be more specific about expectations.  It's quite possible that in writing something like, "because the first one creates an array and the second one yields the error `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`", the OP would recognize the problem and learn much more than by being told.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the working function, you are returning the empty array when n reaches 0. Because of the order of recursion, this is then returned and the calling functions are able to `.push` to the array.

In the non working function, the array is never defined so `.push` doesn't exist.

If you modify your first function like this, it should work.

```
function countup(n) {
  if (n > 0) {
    const countArray = countup(n - 1);
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }

  return [];
}
```

That way, if n > 0 it calls itself, if not, when n reaches 0, it returns the empty array needed for the calling functions to work.

Comment: Thats what I thought too but when  n < 1 is true, should it not just return empty array and exit out of the function. I m not understanding how the pointer goes back to constArray.push(n) if it never had chance to touch it in first place? I guess Im not understanding correct order of execution for each lines of code.

Comment: Imagine rou run the function from 1. 

countup(1) calls countup(0)
countup(0) returns empty array to countup(1) as `countArray`.
countup(1) uses `countArray.push`.

Comment: ...... countup(0) returns empty array to countup(1) as countArray. If that happens, thats true. I think I just couldn't wrap my head around what return means in this recursion scenario. 'return' meant exit the entire method to me. Thanks.

Comment: `return` does exit the entire function at that point, but passes the value back to the calling function. I've corrected your first function to return the empty array, that should work. Hope that helps you understand? Please mark answer if it's ok.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again.